# Remove white bar in appendix when using mini-frames in metropolis theme

Tags: beamer, mini-frames, beamer-metropolis

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=mDarkTeal}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=mDarkTeal}


\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{frame}{slide}
    Normal slide
\end{frame}

\appendix

\begin{frame}{Additional stuff}
    Additional stuff
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I use mini-frames in the metroplis theme to indicate the progress in the presentation. I also use `appendixnumberbeamer` package in order to separate backup slides from the rest of the presentation. In the slides in the appendix, the mini-frames are not visible any more - which is just fine. However, there is a white bar where the mini-frames were located before.
[image]
Is there any possibility to remove this bar completely in the appendix? It would be sufficient to change the outer theme in the appendix slides, but I don't think this is possible without any further ado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply shift the slides from the appendix by the height of the former navigation bar:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=mDarkTeal}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=mDarkTeal}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{frame}{slide}
    Normal slide
\end{frame}

\appendix

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{-\headheight}}{}

\begin{frame}{Additional stuff}
    Additional stuff
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[standout] 
    \frametitle{~}
    \vspace*{-\headheight}
    Thank you very much! 
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I will accept it as an answer. However, do you have any idea how to extend this to the standout frame? `\begin{frame}[standout] Thank you very much! \end{frame}`

Comment: @user1742364 See the edit for a quick hack of the standout-frame.

Comment: @user1742364 You're welcome!