# Removing headline on single frame

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I would like to remove the headline and footline from a single frame define in my .sty with:

```
\newcommand{\frontcover}{
   \beamer@MyStyle@covertrue
   {
      \usebackgroundtemplate{\pgfuseimage{frontcover}}
      \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
      \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
      \frame{}
    }
 \beamer@cMyStyle@coverfalse
 }
```

and called in my .tex with `\frontcover`. The problem is that the headline is removed but a blank space remains. How can I remove both headline and space ?
I tried to add `\vspace*{-2.65ex}` but doesn't seem to change anything.

Thanks

Comment: Would `begin{frame}[plain] ... \end{frame}` be a solution?

Comment: If a plain frame is not an option, have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321885/remove-white-bar-in-appendix-when-using-mini-frames-in-metropolis-theme/321889#321889