# How to set frames plain defaultly?

Tags: beamer

I want to remove footline space in all frames. It seems that the `draft` option give me a gray band in the bottom, and `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}` doesn't kill it. I need the `draft` option to accelerate the typsetting. I found that the frames with `plain` option have no footline gray band perfectly even in draft mode. Can I add `plain` to each frame once time in a default way?

```
\documentclass[14pt,handout,draft,t]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\begin{document}
\frame{ frame 1}
\frame{ frame 2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}` looks correct. Can you show us a MWE where it does not work?

Comment: Where did you insert `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beamer` does some last minute patches, among these is that the footline is replaced with a grey rule in draft mode. To get your desired empty footline, move `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}` after `\begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass[14pt,handout,draft,t]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\begin{frame}
frame 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
frame 2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @scamcarter the space still stand there. Can I remove the vertical head space nicely?

Comment: @MiGang Can you make a MWE and mark which space you want to remove? Maybe in a new question?

Comment: Thanks. I found the solutoin in your another answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321885/remove-white-bar-in-appendix-when-using-mini-frames-in-metropolis-theme